# SQL Query: Combining group by with different record entries

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given the following table and records:

| location | interaction | session |
| --- | --- | --- |
| us | 5 | xyz |
| us | 10 | xyz |
| us | 20 | xyz |
| us | 5 | qrs |
| us | 10 | qrs |
| us | 20 | qrs |
| de | 5 | abc |
| de | 10 | abc |
| de | 20 | abc |
| fr | 5 | mno |
| fr | 10 | mno |

I'm trying to create a query that will get a count of locations for all sessions that have interactions of 5 and 10, but NOT 20.

So assuming the above, the query will return

| count | location |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | us |
| 1 | de |

FR will not be in the results, because session 'mno' did not have an interaction of 20.
As far as I can tell, I need to group by session first, then group by location afterwards. Which might mean using a nested select statement. I've tried a few things, but am not sure how to proceed. Would appreciate any help on how to approach a query like this.

Comment: Your description is wrong. "a count of locations for all sessions that have interactions of 5 and 10, but NOT 20" would only get session mno for fr and no other. But you say you want all others except that one. Please clarify.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your example is wrong - if a location session shall have interactions 5 and 10 but not 20 then only 'fr' shall be in the result as both 'us' and 'de' do have 20 in all their sessions.
SQL fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4a215/11).

```sql
with t as
(
  select location, array_agg(interaction) arr
  from the_table
  group by location, session
)
select count(*) cnt, location 
from t
where arr @> array[5,10] and not arr @> array[20]
group by location;
```